# How to perform query on one to many relations tables using ORM and define serializers for it?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, orm, django-orm

data in request

```
city_name = 'Nashik'
tags = ['tag 1','tag 2', 'tag 3']
```

I try this

```
ws = WorkSamplesModel.objects.filter(business_account__serviceareasmodel__city_name=city_name,
        business_account__professiontagsmodel__tag_name__in=tags_list,
        is_business_card_image=True).distinct()
```

Now I want `business_title ,business_description,status,note`  from BusinessAccountModel and
`work_sample_image, work_sample_description, is_business_card_image` from WorkSampleModel and
`user_name,profile_pic` from UserModel

how to create serializer for it?

*models
I want to find a specific BusinessAccountModel using city_name and tags
and then one WorkSamplesModel for each BusinessAccountModel.*

```
class BusinessAccountModel(models.Model):
    business_title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    business_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'wp_business_acc'


class ProfessionTagsModel(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    business_account = models.ForeignKey(BusinessAccountModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profession_tags'


class ServiceAreasModel(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    business_account = models.ForeignKey(BusinessAccountModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'service_areas'


class WorkSamplesModel(models.Model):
    work_sample_image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to="work_samples")
    work_sample_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_business_card_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    business_account = models.ForeignKey(BusinessAccountModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'work_samples'
```

> BusinessAccountModel - ProfessionTagsModel : 1:M

> BusinessAccountModel - ServiceAreasModel : 1:M

> BusinessAccountModel - WorkSamplesModel : 1:M

Answer (score 0):

```
ws = WorkSamplesModel.objects.filter(business_account__serviceareasmodel__city_name=city_name,
        business_account__professiontagsmodel__tag_name__in=tags_list,
        is_business_card_image=True).distinct()
```

Serializer for it

```
class SearchWorkingProgessionalsSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    business_title = serializers.CharField(source='business_account.business_title')
    business_description = serializers.CharField(source='business_account.business_description')
    status = serializers.CharField(source='business_account.status')
    note = serializers.CharField(source='business_account.note')
    work_sample_image = serializers.ImageField()
    work_sample_description = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).